Is there any separate website on stack exchange for AI agent / tools discussion?
There are 50+ websites under Stack Exchange; is there any website where we can ask about AI tools like Bolt or Claud or Gemini or CoPilot? We have Web Applications but that isn't appropriate.
There are forums and Github pages but do we have anywhere on Stack Exchange ?

https://genai.stackexchange.com/

@JeremyBanks That looks like an answer...

There's also a full list of all the sites here.

You won't find discussion unless they've a chat room to join that is.
